# LinearLayout widget cannot be cast to Textview Widget, Listview in popupwindow

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, popup

okay, so i'm having this problem, where i have a popup that contains a Listview and i'm trying to get the Selected String of data into  textview in the main activity outside of the popup, all worked normally when the listview is within the main activity but when i put it in a popup i started getting

```
android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

here is the code for from the popup where i try to retrieve the string:

```
word_lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        //click listener for items within list
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //cast the view


            TextView wordView = (TextView) view;
            //retrieve the chosen word
            String wordChosen = (String) wordView.getText();

            Log.v("WORD: ", "chosen: " + wordChosen);
            //output Toast message
            Toast.makeText(viewpop.this, "You said: " + wordChosen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            repeatTTS.speak("You said: " + wordChosen, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            finish();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           sug_wrd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.words_string);
           sug_wrd.setText(wordChosen);


        }
```

here is the popup XML:

```
    LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/view_List"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/words_bg"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
     />
 </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the XML for the textview from the main activity(it's the view_btn one):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view_btn"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/view_all"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sug_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sug_btn"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT : here is my OnCreate for the popupwindow

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //call superclass
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set contect view
    setContentView(R.layout.popupview);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .9), (int) (height * .7));
    //---
    word_lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view_List);
    DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = db.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur1 = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM wordsdata ORDER BY Enno DESC", null);
    TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cur1);
    word_lst.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, word_lst, false);
    word_lst.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Comment: can you add the code snippet where you are setting adapter for ListView

Comment: done! check it out @Sanjeet

Comment: you have to change `TextView wordView = (TextView) view;` to `TextView wordView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);` @lua

Comment: wait hold on, i'm getting the string from the listview, so how is the (yourtextviewId) thing should work? like, what textview ID are we talking about here? i think i'm missing something here @Sanjeet

Comment: here view will be the root layout(not TextView) which has been used to inflate in ListView. so if try to cast it to TextView it will throw exception @lua

Comment: or you can create one method in adapter to return the word base on position. Then in onItemClick `String wordChosen = todoAdapter.getItem(position);`

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to cast the view to TextView in the line

```
TextView wordView = (TextView) view;
```

so remove this line and put a textview in the layout and call it by code.
For the line

```
String wordChosen = (String) wordView.getText();
```

correct it to 
String wordChosen = wordView.getText().toString();

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: hi, yeah what do you mean by put a textview in the layout?

Comment: in your xml file i mean put a text view

Comment: in the popup XML? what for? what does it do?

Comment: i'm asking because i dont understand, i'm retrieving a String from Listview in the popup window and putting it in the textview in the main activity